# Generate very Uniquer number in PHP - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, random

I am developing a very big application where i want to create very very unique random numbers which will never ever match the previous records.Here is my code

```
function random_number($maxlength = 17) {
    $chary = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
                    "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
                    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
    $return_str = "";
    for ( $x=0; $x<=$maxlength; $x++ ) {
        $return_str .= $chary[rand(0, count($chary))];
    }
    return $return_str;
}
```

Now it works fine but some time it give me error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 62 in test.php on line 8
```

Where line 8 is

```
$return_str .= $chary[rand(0, count($chary))];
```

Can anyone fix this for me?

Secondly is there any function in CI for random numbers?

Comment: You could use codeigniter-uuid to generate ids https://github.com/Repox/codeigniter-uuid

Comment: change `count($chary)` to `count($chary)-1`

Comment: use `str_shuffle()`.

Comment: @ChetanAmeta count($chary)-1 still give me the same error

Comment: It doesn't make sense, `$return_str .= $chary[rand(0, count($chary)-1)];` shouldn't trigger an offset notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php),

> int rand ( int $min , int $max )
>
> If called without the optional min, max arguments rand() returns a pseudo-random integer between 0 and getrandmax(). If you want a random number between 5 and 15 **(inclusive)**, for example, use rand(5, 15).

So you have to change the range parameter in `rand()` function, from `rand(0, count($chary))` to `rand(0, count($chary)-1)`

```
function random_number($maxlength = 17) {
    $chary = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
                    "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
                    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
    $return_str = "";
    for ( $x=0; $x<=$maxlength; $x++ ) {
        $return_str .= $chary[rand(0, count($chary)-1)];
    }
    return $return_str;
}
```

Comment: If length should be as written (i.e. 17 chars), `$x=0` should be `$x=1`.

Comment: @Tpojka hmm, it could be, but OP's question is about *undefined offset*, not about underlying business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) it is standard php function and you dont need to invent your own bicycle. There is downsides in it but its other topic.

Comment: @maxhb nice catch :) at least i linked it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> I am developing a very big application where i want to create very very unique random numbers which will never ever match the previous records

Then don't use any of these functions:

- `rand()`
- `mt_rand()`
- `lcg_value()`
- `str_shuffle()`
- `uniqid()`

They're all weak. Instead, you want [`random_int()`](https://secure.php.net/random_int). Otherwise, the accepted answer is... acceptable.